# Экспорт данных в файл на локальный сервер

Tags: mysql

Я подключаюсь к удалённой базе данных и хочу сохранить данные из таблицы в файл на локальный сервер. Насколько я знаю, команда

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE '/file_name.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

сохраняет данные в файл на хосте сервера.

Можно ли сохранить данные из таблицы в файл на локальный сервер, и если да, то как?

**P.S.** Было бы идеально, если бы это можно было сделать средствами SQLyog.

Comment: Если только по sftp примонтировать локальную директорию на удаленный сервер

Comment: Так, собственно, в `SQLyog` можно настроить доступ к удаленному серваку... там на вкладке `Mysql`  можно настроить ip, порт, логин и пароль к подключаемой базе....или не работает?....в зависимости кто заведует этой БД, возможно понадобиться досуп через SSH настроить (у админа попросить ip лог пас или public key)

Comment: вот я на сайте https://www.db4free.net/  создал тестовую бд ... можете попробовать войти через SQLYog сами и убедиться что работает : `имя сервера:  db4free.net
порт:  3306
База данных: testyoyotest
Username: testyoyotest
pass: qwerty`